# How to configure a free FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) for local usage?

Tags: dns, nginx, webserver, domain, reverse-proxy

I'm using a free `FQDN` of `mordor.bounceme.net` and [am trying](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/12751/23443) to run `ERPNext` from docker, but need to configure it properly.

I'm only looking to run it on "localhost" and don't need, nor want it, publicly available.

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ dig mordor.bounceme.net

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> mordor.bounceme.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43186
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mordor.bounceme.net.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mordor.bounceme.net.    49  IN  A   8.23.224.108

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov 13 15:05:16 PST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 64

nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ dig erp.mordor.bounceme.net

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> erp.mordor.bounceme.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 49004
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;erp.mordor.bounceme.net.   IN  A

;; Query time: 59 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov 13 15:05:19 PST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52

nicholas@mordor:~$
```

But I don't need `dig` to give correct results for either, I just need this machine, which is running the `ERPNext` container, to be accessible through the web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `/etc/hosts` `man  5 hosts` for further information. It is used before DNS lookup to find a hostname's IP address.